# Add a column to an existing matrix

Tags: r

I have created a matrix of 100 random numbers

```
set.seed(1)
datae=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1)
```

Now I need to add another column to this matrix with a sum of the previous row, keeping the first row value `[1,2]` same as `[1,1]`

E.g.: the result would be cumulative like:

```
#           [,1]       [,2]
#[1,] -0.6264538 -0.6264538
#[2,]  0.1836433 -0.4428105
#[3,] -0.8356286 -1.2784391
#[4,]  1.5952808  0.3168417
#[5,]  0.3295078  0.6463495
#[6,] -0.8204684 -0.1741189
# ...
```

I am a newbie and have been trying this for the last 45 minutes.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sounds like it might belong on mathematics.stackexchange.com? Are you even programming this?

Comment: @ Tim , I am using R, and R Studio

Comment: @user5501025 - it's not clear what you want. Take a different example, e.g. `test <- matrix(1:5)` what would your new column look like?

Comment: [,1]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2+1=3
[3,]    3     3+3=6
[4,]    4     6+4=10
[5,]    5     10+5=15
>the new column should be previous row Added to next row, like a cummulative, except for row 1

Comment: Please edit your question. The comment section is not the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
datae=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1)
x <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100)
for(i in 1:100){
  x[i] <- sum(datae[1:i,1])
}
new <- cbind(datae, x)
```

new should be a 100x2 matrix with the 2nd column being a sum of all the previous rows of your first column.

**Edit**: As thelatemail pointed out below vectorised solutions in R are preferable whenever possible. Using `cbind(datae, cumsum(datae[,1]) )` instead of the above code is both cleaner and more efficient. Thanks.

Comment: Use vectorised functions wherever possible, this is equivalent to `cbind(datae, cumsum(datae[,1]) )` , `cumsum` being the `cum`ulative `sum` of a vector, e.g. `cumsum(1:5)`